# Fixed text at end of textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

Is there any way to get a fixed, default text on the end of the text in a textarea? Why? I have a textarea to make twitter stsatuses, and at the end, every user have to have their signature. So I want to have it in the text, that they can't delete.

Any code or plugin to do that?

Comment: Have you considered taking what they enter in the text area, and when they click submit (or tweet or whatever you crazy kids are calling it these days) running it through a function that appends the user signature automatically?

Comment: Yes, have so. But would like that kind of UI to let the user know what he/she posts.

Comment: Bit of an overall question here...twitter only allows 140 characters, having a "signature" seems very detrimental to actual usability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is too old already and I was thinking if you got any good solution to your question cause I was almost like doing the same thing here. If not, maybe you'd want to check my answer here http://jsfiddle.net/index/tX44C/2/ .

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar problem not too long ago.  Instead of a fixed text, I decided to limit the number of works they could add to the twitter text area so that instead of 140 characters allowed, only 110 characters were allowed.  I enforced this using jquery, on the client side and also verified it on the server side.

**In your case use the same code as below but replace:**

```
tweet = $('#edit-tweet').val();
```

with

```
tweet = $('#edit-tweet').val() + 'Your Signature';
```

This is the code I used on the client side:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var tweet_area = $('#edit-tweet');

    tweet_area.keyup(count_down);

    count_down();

    dim();

    tweet_area.hover(highlight, dim);

  });


/**
 * Count down function
 */
function count_down() {
  var left = 110 - $('#edit-tweet').val().length;

  if (left < 0) {
    left = 0;
    limit_text(tweet);
  } else {
    tweet = $('#edit-tweet').val();
  }
  $('#counter').text(' - ' + left);
}

/**
 * Limits the tweet text value to static sized tweet.
 * 
 * @param tweet
 *          the static sized tweet
 */
function limit_text(tweet) {
  $('#edit-tweet').val(tweet);
}

/**
 * Callback for hover in function
 */
function highlight() {

  var tweet_style_focusin = {
    'width' : '600px',
    'height' : '50px',
    'border' : '3px solid #cccccc',
    'padding' : '5px',
    'font-family' : 'Tahoma, sans-serif',
    'background-image' : 'url(bg.gif)',
    'background-position' : 'bottom right',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'
  };

  $(this).css(tweet_style_focusin);

  $(this).focus();

}

/**
 * Callback for hover out function
 */
function dim() {
  var tweet_style_foucsout = {
    'width' : '600px',
    'height' : '50px',
    'border' : '1px solid #cccccc',
    'padding' : '5px',
    'font-family' : 'Tahoma, sans-serif',
    'background-image' : 'url(bg.gif)',
    'background-position' : 'bottom right',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'

  };

  $('#edit-tweet').css(tweet_style_foucsout);
}
```

Comment: Yea, have that kind of code allready. I'm asking how I can add an alias at the end of the text to show the user how the message will look like. Not hide the alias, then add it when they post.

Comment: You would use the same code then... except replace the the tweet with tweet + constant ... `tweet = $('#edit-tweet').val() + 'Your Signature';`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but I would use another approach. You can add an disabled textarea or simply a div under the textarea for the main text.

```
<textarea name="blabla"><textarea>
<div class="signature">signature</div>
```

And than do the job in the backend.

I don't know what your using.

So for php something like this:

```
<?php $_POST['blabla'] .= $signature ?>
```

In rails something like this:

```
def some_action
  params[:blabla] << signature
end
```

This way the user can't change the signature in no way. Even if you find a jQuery solution that works, it always isn't secure, because the user can change the javascript code, or disable it completely, than the user is able to change his signature.

IMHO a server side approach is the best way to do this.

Comment: Would of course have a server side check before the update is made ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `div` of exactly the same width under the `textarea`. I'd try to make them look like one solid `textarea` as much as possible by making sure the borders and backgrounds are consistent and eliminating the bottom border of the `textarea` and the top border of the `div` using CSS.

Comment: Thought of that, but would rater have the alias at the end of the text. `Some long message here /alias`, but that the /alias is allways at the end.